# HttpUrlConnection, отправить на сервер POST запрос, содержащий JSON

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

Здравствуйте. Есть сервер, куда нужно отправить POST-запрос, чтобы в дальнейшем обработать его. Как это сделать с помощью HttpUrlConnection?

Answer (score 0):

```
String urlParameters  = "param1=a&param2=b&param3=c";
byte[] postData       = urlParameters.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
int    postDataLength = postData.length;
String request        = "http://example.com/index.php";
URL    url            = new URL( request );
HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
conn.setDoOutput( true );
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
conn.setUseCaches( false );
try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream())) {
   wr.write( postData );
}
```

Comment: а в параметрах(urlParameters) что записывается?

Comment: @qwerty а что не ясно с `String urlParameters  = "param1=a&param2=b&param3=c";`?

Comment: в заголовке вопроса написано про JSON, а вы советуете form-url-encoded, ай-ай-ай. @moon_cherry, используйте вместо conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); другой контент тайп conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/json"); должно получиться